# CountIfs function with two criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have a database, with gender values (M, F) in Column H, and age range values (<12, 12-14, 15-21, 22-35, 36-45, 46-60, >60) are in Column J.

For example, I would want to count the number of males in the age-range 12-14.

This COUNTIFS formula works for the hyphenated age range values, but is not counting the <12 and >60 values:

```
=COUNTIFS(H4:H1000,"M",J4:J1000,"<12")
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
=COUNTIFS(H4:H1000,"M",J4:J1000,">=12",J4:J1000,"<=60")
```

Also I would advise to fix the ranges so that they don't shift when you fill the formula down:

```
=COUNTIFS($H$4:$H$1000,"M",$J$4:$J$1000,">=12",$J$4:$J$1000,"<=60")
```

Or even better:

```
=COUNTIFS($H:$H,"M",$J:$J,">=12",$J:$J,"<=60")
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP doesn't have numbers in column J, but literal ranges.

Answer (score 0):

When you write <12 in the condition, Excel interprets it as : count the numbers that are lower than 12, and it doesn't find any, because there is none. To count the lines that contain exactly "<12", you can write :

```
=COUNTIFS(H4:H1000,"M",J4:J1000,"=<12")
```

The = sign, before <12, prevents the rest of the string from being interpreted.